# Creating an accuracy system

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can someone explain me how can i build an accuracy system for a game , for example i want a move to have 90% chance to hit , or maybe 60%.I thought by using this method:

```
var radnomNum = Math.random()*10;

if(randomNum >= 2){
//it will hit , and the chance is about 80%
}else{
// it will miss , 20% chacne
}
```

but it seems like it doesn't create such chances.

Comment: Shouldn't that be Math.random() * 100 ?

Comment: Things to do before asking a question: Check your spelling

Comment: @aleksXPO If that was actually the problem you shouldn't fix it in your question, as it's then impossible to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work. [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will return a random number between 0 and 1, so you don't have to multiply it by 10.

You also spelled `randomNum` as `radnomNum` in your example, which is probably why it doesn't work.

```
var randomNumber = Math.random();
if (randomNumber <= 0.8) {
    //80% chance
} else {
    //20% chance
}
```

Comment: Thanks , and yeah i misspelled it.

Comment: @aleksXPO Any error console would've told you that `randomNumber` was undefined. Eg. Chrome tells me *ReferenceError: randomNumber is not defined*.

Comment: i wrote the code hear not in a text editor , i just wanted an explanation how accuracy works , and yours was good.